# bunzip between multiple directories, loop

Tags: file, loops, directory

I am trying to write a loop in a bash script to move through my directory tree to bunzip files my problem is, is that if i leave the 008 then it works but i have 001 through 365, which means i would have to change the directory 365 times making the loop pointless. What is the command to cd * then bunzip each file then cd back one directory to do it again.

## !/usr/bin/bash

cd ../y2014/

topdir=../y2014/

for f in topdir

do
    cd 008 && bunzip2 *.nc.bz2
done

Answer (score 0):

**cd -**

will cd to the previous directory

Comment: bunzip2: Can't open input file *.nc.bz2: No such file or directory.                       this is the error i get

Comment: HI. Some suggestions to get some more assistance: 1 - Give a more complete example of your directory structure.  2 -explain step-by-step what you want done. I think with both of those to work with, people will be more willing/able to give you specific guidance.